# Read excel file without dto while using spring batch

Tags: excel, spring-batch

I am  new to spring batch and with some analysis I have come to know that there are many readers available out of the box from spring batch to bulk process data. I have an requirement where Input excel sheet is  dynamic and I need to read it and bulk import data to sql db. All of the examples I have seen uses an dto to map the excel row to objects and then process it. I will not be able to create dto for each and every file as the  requirement is to have dynamic import capability. Is there anyway it can be achieved using spring batch?  Any thoughts will be helpful

Comment: Hi Bala, Welcome to stackoverflow.  Please read this article and edit your question in an appropriate fashion that will make this useful for everyone.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Use a `Map` for your DTO...